# I had one multi select dropdown , if i select user i had to open another dropdown which contain user roles

Tags: html, angular

Here i had one selection in which user is populated,now if i am select
user i want another dropdown next to user for selection of user roles.

Currently i am doing like this,but it does not solve my problem.
When i am doing this the values `admin`,`member`,...are shown in the input:

```
<mat-select
        placeholder="User"
        name="Users"
        formControlName="Users"
        multiple
        ngDefaultControl>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let user of userList"
                    [value]="user.id">
                    {{user.UserName}}
        <select>
            <option value="admin">Admin</option>
            <option value="member">Member</option>
            <option value="leader">Leader</option>
        </select>
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? Do you want to use select within a select?

Comment: Please adjust the formatting of your question to not be in a quote block, since it is not quoted.

Comment: Yes For each user inside my select i have to use another selection for the role. @Prachi

Comment: You can use a select tree, in which each option has options within it. Refer this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-tree-select

Comment: its fine, but in my case first user is loaded in selection drop-down for particular user i want user role selection.